# How to specify multiple parameters for authorization on HttpClient?

Tags: c#, oauth, http-headers, authorization, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying the following approach, which fails because of the authorization issues. I know what a correct authorization string in the headers look like in the browser.

> oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT"
>   oauth_consumer_key="beep"
>   oauth_token="boop"
>   oauth_signature="baap";

I've tried to improve it by specifying

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
  AuthenticationHeaderValue header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "oauth_signature_method", "PLAINTEXT");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;

  HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(url);
  result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

However, I get stuck because I'm not sure how to specify multiple parameters of the authorization part of the header. Also, when I execute the above, I get the error message that signature method must be set to plain text, so I'm fairly certain that even this approach might be flawed like a crazy pig.

Googling gave me nothing, except examples where people only specify a single parameter.

Comment: Just add your header to the "Headers" collection. Authentication is for "bearer, un/pwd".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it might be needed to skip the validation then using *Add()*.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", header);
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net)

In your case you can add something like this:

```
    var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

    var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
        );
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
```